# How to add combo box events in sap Ui5

Tags: sapui5

I am using combo box in a table having two fields as male and female and if i change that value to be stored in the JSON model data..How to use an event to it..

The following is my code

```
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column( {
                 label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Gender"}),
                 template: new sap.ui.commons.ComboBox(
                                {items: [new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "Female"}),
                                new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "Male"})]}).bindProperty("value","gender"),
                 sortProperty: "gender",
                 filterProperty: "gender",                   
                 enabled : true,                     
                 change: function(oEvent){
                    sap.ui.getCore().byId("gender").setValue(oEvent.oSource.getSelectedItemId());
                 },
                 width: "75px"
                 }));
    function change(oEvent){
                 var bEnabled = oEvent.getParameter("enabled");
                 // modify the enabled property value in the model to reflect changes
                 oModel.setData({enabled: bEnabled}, true); // true means merge the data instead of replacing
      };
```

But it is not reflecting the values..please correct the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should move your `change` function to the combobox, currently is is attached to the column (which does not have an event like that).
2. you can put your `bindProperty`-call to the constructor
3. in the event-function you have to get the model and change its value.

```
new sap.ui.commons.ComboBox({
    value: "{gender}",
    items: [
        new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
            text: "Female"
        }), new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
            text: "Male"
        })
    ],
    change: function(oEvent) {
        var newValue = oEvent.getParameter("newValue");
        var bindingPath = this.getBindingPath("value");
        this.getModel().setProperty(bindingPath, newValue);
    }
})
```

Comment: i used the provided code but not reflecting the changes..If i change in the table(combo box) then if i refreshed then again displaying previous value after adding an event also..I am beginner to SAP UiI5